# Search Regex to match string

Tags: java, regex

Hey im searching for a working regex for

I tried something like this `^([-])?(([(])?[-|]{0}[a-zA-z0-9|]([)])?([.])?)+$` but it isn't very nice.

It should match:

```
world.block.(1-2|1).(test1|stack)
test.test.(1-2|1)
world.(test1|stack)
-help.block.(1-2|1).(test1|stack)
```

but it shouldn't match

```
-world.help
 world.stack
 world.block.
```

All literals are examples!

Comment: not clear, what is your input and what is it that you are trying to match?

Comment: I think you forgot to tell us what you need the regex to match

Comment: in that case, try this regex:  `(world\.block\.\(1-2\|1\)\.\(test1\|stack\))|(-world\.block\.\(1-2\|1\)\.\(test1\|stack\)|(world\.block\.\(1-2\|1\)))|(world\.\(test1\|stack\))`

Comment: Are the literals "world", "block", "test", "help", "test1" and "stack" actually literals or just examples of the pattern?

Comment: all literals are example

Comment: What about the numbers? Are they exact or examples? If examples, what are the allowed ranges in there?

Comment: They are also examples. the range should be from 1-500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some Java code that should do what you wanted:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^-?([^\\.]+\\.){1,2}\\((\\d+-\\d+|\\d+)|([^|]+|[^|]+)\\)$");
    String[] samples = { "world.block.(1-2|1).(test1|stack)",
        "test.test.(1-2|1)",
        "world.(test1|stack)",
        "-help.block.(1-2|1).(test1|stack)",
        "-world.help",
        "world.stack",
        "world.block."
    };

    for (String sample : samples) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sample);
        System.out.println(sample + (matcher.find() ? " matched" : " failed"));
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
world.block.(1-2|1).(test1|stack) matched
test.test.(1-2|1) matched
world.(test1|stack) matched
-help.block.(1-2|1).(test1|stack) matched
-world.help failed
world.stack failed
world.block. failed
```

The only thing missing is range checking the digits.  It's possible to add that in, but I would rather use a matching group and do a range check with math instead to avoid overcomplicating the regex.